# Vscode intelisense duplicates in require/import statements (JS)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When typing require or import I get duplicates in module autocompletion, one of which is commented as 'npm dependencies'.
Does someone have insight into why this happens and how I can control this and remove the duplicate?
I have @types/npm installed, may be it is connected.
[image: scr1]
[image: scr2]

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @MattBierner 
Bracket pair colorizer, Debugger for Chrome, DotENV, Firebase, Go, language-stylus,Material Icon Theme, Material Theme, npm, Prettier, TODO Highlight. I tried disabling npm, but it didn't make a difference